# Google Api PHP Client - Call to undefined method UsersSettingsSendAs::list()

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-workspace

We are trying to get a list of 'sendAs' emails from a user with the latest version (2.13.2) of Google APIs Client Library for PHP.

```php
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->list('my@email.tld');
```

Error 500 appears and this line on apache log:

```
[Mon Apr 24 12:50:37.233655 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4185936:tid 139798719207168] [client 90.161.67.44:35704] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\\Service\\Gmail\\Resource\\UsersSettingsSendAs::list() in /path/to/index.php:19\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /path/to/index.php on line 19'
```

If I try another method (get, for example) works as expected ...

```php
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->get('my@email.tld','my@email.tld')->getSignature();
```

The file api/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Gmail.php has get and list ...

```php
$this->users_settings_sendAs = new Gmail\Resource\UsersSettingsSendAs(
        $this,
        $this->serviceName,
        'sendAs',
        [
          'methods' => [
            ...,'get' => [
              'path' => 'gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/sendAs/{sendAsEmail}',
              'httpMethod' => 'GET',
              'parameters' => [
                'userId' => [
                  'location' => 'path',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ],
                'sendAsEmail' => [
                  'location' => 'path',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ],
              ],
            ],'list' => [
              'path' => 'gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/sendAs',
              'httpMethod' => 'GET',
              'parameters' => [
                'userId' => [
                  'location' => 'path',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'required' => true,
                ],
              ],
            ],...
```

I've tried to get the sendAs emails list from a user, but an error occurred (undefined method). Any ideas? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct code:

```php
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$response = $gmail->users_settings_sendAs->listUsersSettingsSendAs('my@email.tld');
```

The key is use `listUsersSettingsSendAs()` instead of `list()`

One of my colleagues find it at `vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Gmail/Resource/UsersSettingsSendAs.php`

```php
  /**
   * Lists the send-as aliases for the specified account. The result includes the
   * primary send-as address associated with the account as well as any custom
   * "from" aliases. (sendAs.listUsersSettingsSendAs)
   *
   * @param string $userId User's email address. The special value "me" can be
   * used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
   * @return ListSendAsResponse
   */
  public function listUsersSettingsSendAs($userId, $optParams = [])
  {
    $params = ['userId' => $userId];
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('list', [$params], ListSendAsResponse::class);
  }
```

Thank's A.C.!